# Como editar página após renderizada com Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Eu preciso que a cada vez que for renderizada uma página com um path qualquer seja adicionado um parágrafo depois do `<body>` e outro paragrafo antes do `</body>`.

Estou usando Express.js e da para fazer isso pegando o retorno de string do `app.render` e após manipulá-lo rodar um `res.write`. Porém dessa forma eu teria que repetir o código para todas as rotas e minha intenção é fazer isso como se fosse um middleware executado com único `app.use`.

Comment: Só por curiosidade, qual engine de templates voce esta usando? Jade?

Comment: @renatoargh Uso ejs.

Comment: Isto ajuda?



 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843840/how-does-res-renderview-locals-callback-work-node-js-express-module

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com o [código fonte do express](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/40f7a8eaa297c26f74c1a5dbc13ab705b6f97b45/lib/response.js#L926-L933) você pode passar um callback para a função `res.render`, caso você não passe um callback você pode perceber que o próprio express fornece um callback padrão que invoca `res.send` com o resultado da renderização.

Você pode alterar a string renderizada como quiser a partir deste callback, porém sabemos que é muito dificil alterar o string HTML na mão, neste caso você pode usar um modulo como [cheerio](http://npmjs.org/package/cheerio) para fazer esta manipulação.

#### Aplicando a todas as rotas

Um mecanismo para adotar esta solução em todas as rotas seria mais ou menos assim;

```
function alterarResposta(next) {
    return function(err, renderedView) {
        if(err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        res.modifyResponse = true;
        res.renderedView = renderedView;
        next();
    }
}

app.get('/helloWorld', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('helloWorld', alterarResposta(next));
});

app.get('/fooBar', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('fooBar', alterarResposta(next));
});

// Aqui vem todas as suas outras rotas!

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if(!res.modifyResponse) {
        return res.send(res.renderedView);
    }

    //Aqui você modifica sua resposta
    res.send(res.renderedView);
});
```

OBS.: Você pode colocar a função alterar resposta num outro arquivo `.js`

Embora os paragrafos acima respondam sua pergunta eu particularmente não adotaria esta solução (eu não pensaria em modificar a resposta antes de enviar). Eu ia preferir utilizar um mecanismo nos próprios templates, algum tipo de [include](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/) ou `import` (não sei qual nomenclatura é usada no EJS) de forma que todos os templates importassem automaticamente este conteudo adicional. Essa segunda abordagem é menos trabalhosa e menos passível de erro.